# Finding the Value of K in an Integral Function

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Given the function $$f(x)\begin{cases}
-2(x+1),  & \text{x $\le0$} \\
k(1-x^2), & \text{x $\gt0$}  \\
\end{cases}$$

Find the value of k for $$\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx=1$$

Wasn't really sure how to do this but this is what I did:

Integrate first function from -1 to 0:

$$\int_{-1}^0-2(x+1)=-1$$

Second Integral:

$$\int_0^1k(1-x^2) = 2$$
$$= \left[kx-\frac{kx^3}{3}\right]_0^1=2$$
$$k-\frac{k}{3}=2$$
$$\frac{2}{3}k=2$$
$$k=3$$

So therefore k must be 3 for $\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx=1$

Is this correct?

Comment: Fixed after failure of an integral... how is it now

Comment: i think as something wrong on first integral.

Comment: OK done.. check if im right polease

Comment: The first integral is wrong now

Comment: sorry there was a typo in my writing, its editted properly now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first integral is incorrect:

$$\int_{-1}^0-2(x+1)$$

$$\left[-x^2 - 2x\right]_{-1}^0$$

$$0-(-1+2) = -1$$

**EDIT**

The OP made an error within the question. His work and answer are both correct now.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my calculation integral. The f(x) is the correct equation.. sorry about this..

Comment: Okay then your work is correct

Comment: @Panthy: Check again your first integral.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine.  Indeed it is $-3$.  Please care about the continuously of the function on the given interval, however it doesn't need here. A simple code in Maple could get us that $k$:

```
[> f := x->(-1 <= x and x <= 0, -2*x-2, 0 < x and x <= 1, 3-3*x^2):
solve(int(f(x), x = -1 .. 1) = 1, k);


                                        3
```

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+-2%28x%2B1%29+from+-1+to+0

Comment: Indeed k = 3 but I was just messing up the integral of the first equation where I ended up getting -3 as the area from -1 to 0 which was confusing everyone